# For all even integers $n$, $(-1)^n = 1$

Tags: proof-verification

Suppose that $n$ is an even integer.

Then $n = 2r$ for some $r \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Hence $(−1)^n =(−1)^{2r} = 1$ because $2r$ is even.

Therefore $(−1)^n = 1$ for any even integer $n$

Verification?

Comment: Basically, you need to write $(-1)^n=(-1)^{2r}=((-1)^2)^r=(+1)^r=1$.

Comment: @barakmanos $\sqrt{a}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}$, while $a^{-2}=\frac{1}{a^2}$

Comment: @edm: Ooops, long hours :)

Comment: This is completely circular.  Why does $(-1)^{2r} = 1$?  You say it is because $2r$ is even.  That's what you are trying to prove!  You can't use what you are trying to prove to prove it!

Comment: Prove all numbers are  less than 523.  Let $n$ be a number.  Let $n =r+1$.  $r+1 < 253$ because it is a number.  Therefore all $n < 253$.  What is wrong with my proof?  My proof is **exactly** the same reasoning as your proof.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't prove anything yet. I am sorry, but your current "solution" is worth $0$ points.

Why?

---

You say

> $(-1)^{2r} = 1$ because $2r$ is even.

But *how do you know that if $2r$ is even, $(-1)^{2r} = 1$*?

You cannot just **assume** the conclusion!

---

That's not how mathematical proofs work. Remember that what you want to prove is the statement:

> If $n$ is even, then $(-1)^n=1$.

In your current "proof", you basically say,

> I already know that  if $2r$ is even, then $(-1)^n=1$.

But **you don't know that** because that is exactly what you want to prove.

---

**Hint**:

For the actual solution, remember that ${\left(a^b\right)}^c = a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 2):

You know 
$$(-1)^2=1$$, therefore $$(-1)^{2r} = ((-1)^{2})^r = 1^{r} = 1 $$
for any r.

Answer (score 1):

$$ (-1)^2 = (-1) \times (-1) = 1 $$
hence

$$\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad (-1)^{2r} = \left((-1)^2\right)^r = 1^r = 1.$$